# Font-display, not working in a speed insights

Tags: html, css, fonts, lighthouse

I need to optimize my page at work (my first job as web dev) and i can't get rid of font-display error message at speed insights. I've googled, i've read docs, blogs, forums etc. and i think im expert in this topic now however still speed insights doesn't accept it. Why is that? Please send help :)

Problem seems to occur with fontawesome, not with regular fonts, i've dealt with those. I have fonts downloaded offline, im importing them, and importing stylesheet. Code below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fa-brands-400';
    src: url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    font-display: swap;

    font-family: 'fa-regular-400';
    src: url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('/fontawesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    font-display: swap;

    font-family: 'fa-solid-900';
    src: url('../fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('../fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('../fontawesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error? does the font not show?

Comment: https://codepen.io/caraya/pen/pzFKD this pen may be helpful - you're wrapping all your fonts in one `font-face`.

Comment: not working stands for everything works on the site, font is displayed but speed insights doesn't pass audit. I'll try this pen